# Django получение всех id из базы

Tags: python, django

При работе с django понадобилось написать скрипт для заполнения базы данными для дальнейшего тестирования

Есть таблица в которой необходимо ссылаться на другую ( ранее заполненую) таблицу, для этого я вынимаю из заполненной таблицы все `id` записей при помощи функции:

```
def listId(Entity):
    list_id = Entity.objects.values_list('id')
    if not list_id:
        exit(0)
    return list_id
```

Где `Entity` это сущность( модель ) отвечающая данной таблице, но при выводе `list_id` на экран выдается:

> QuerySet [(10919745,), (10919746,), (10919747,), (10919748,),
>   (10919749,), (10919750,), (10919751,), (10919752,), (10919753,),
>   (10919754,)]

это пораждает 2 вопроса:

1. Почему в таблице такие странные `id`?

формирование данных для этой таблицы идет в функции:

```
def generateWModel(N):
    print("\nWModel\n")
    roll = []
    personal = e.Personal('is')

    for i in range(int(N)):
        roll.append(WModel(
            wname = personal.name(gender = 'male')
        ))
        print(roll[i - 1])

    return roll
```

и заносится в таблицу функцией:

```
def commit(data, Entity):
    try:
        mess = Entity.objects.bulk_create(data)
        print(mess)
    except Exception as ex:
        print(ex)
        return
```

На данный момент там лежит не более 50 записей

2. Почему формат элементов `list_id` такой странный, с запятой в конце

> 10919745,

Answer (score 0):

1. Удаляем базу и при генерации задавать явно `id` новой записи:

   ```
   def generateWModel(N):
       print("\nWModel\n")
       roll = []
       try:
           n = WModel.objects.last().id
       except Exception as i:
           print(i)
           n = 0
       print(n)
       personal = e.Personal('is')

       for i in range(int(N)):
           roll.append(WModel(
               pk = i + n + 1,
               wname = personal.name(gender = 'male')
           ))
           print(roll[i - 1])

       return roll
   ```

   Для начала, при помощи `n = WModel.objects.last().id` вынимаем `id` последней записи, далее при помощи `pk = i + n + 1` задаем `id` новой записи в базу.
2. Использовать `list_id = Entity.objects.values_list('id', flat=True)`